# Android service binding null

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-service-binding

I built this app just to learn android. It says the service binding is null when I try to invoke a method on it. Compiles fine and fails at run time. Thank you for your help!

New error after moving loadAnimals() to onServiceConnected():

```
11-14 11:09:50.610 2978-2978/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.jacob_w.animalList/com.jacob_w.animalList.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.jacob_w.animalList.IAnimalInterface }
```

Main logic fragment:

```
public class AnimalListFragment extends ListFragment implements ServiceConnection {
    IAnimalInterface mAnimalInterfaceBinder = null;

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mAnimalInterfaceBinder = IAnimalInterface.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mAnimalInterfaceBinder = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().bindService(new Intent("com.jacob_w.animalList.IAnimalInterface"), this,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        getActivity().unbindService(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void loadAnimals() {
        SystemClock.sleep(2000);

        AnimalList animalList;
        try {
            animalList = mAnimalInterfaceBinder.getAnimalList();
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {}
    }
}
```

The AIDL interface:

```
import com.jacob_w.animalList.AnimalList;

interface IAnimalInterface {
    AnimalList getAnimalList();
}
```

The object definition:

```
parcelable AnimalList;
```

The service:

```
public class AnimalService extends Service {
    private AnimalList animalList = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mAnimalInterfaceBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    public void updateAnimals() {
        return animalList; // Stub
    }

    private final IAnimalInterface.Stub mAnimalInterfaceBinder = new IAnimalInterface.Stub() {
        public AnimalList getAnimalList() {
            return animalList;
        }
    }
}
```

The object:

```
public final class AnimalList implements Parcelable {
    public String[] animals;
    public String[] links;

    public AnimalList(String[] animals, String[] links) {
        this.animals = animals;
        this.links = links;
    }

    public static final Creator<AnimalList> CREATOR = new Creator<AnimalList>() {
        @Override
        public AnimalList createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new AnimalList(source);
        }

        @Override
        public AnimalList[] newArray(int size) {
            return new AnimalList[size];
        }
    };

    private AnimalList(Parcel animalParcel) {
        animals = animalParcel.createStringArray();
        links = animalParcel.createStringArray();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeStringArray(animals);
        dest.writeStringArray(links);
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably, you are calling `loadAnimals()` before `onServiceConnected()` is called.

Comment: I'm calling it in onCreate. What is the best way to make sure it's loaded before using the service?

Comment: Call it in `onServiceConnected()`.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I'm getting a new error now that I think is because my book is outdated. Error put at the top of post.

Comment: No ideas? And if you think there's issues with the post can you be more specific? Feels like I followed the article.